# Python passing char * as an argument to a function

Tags: python, c++, string, cython

I have created a python module from a C++ static library using the Cython add-on. The C++ library provides a function for listing the contents of a folder. It provides the name of the directory whose contents are to be displayed, as well as an output buffer where the contents of the directory will be stored, and of course the length of the output buffer.
The C++ definition of the function is as follows:

```
int ListItems(char *dir, char *buf, int buflen)
```

The python module then in turn has a function `PyListItems` which simply calls this function:

```
def PyListItems(char *dir, char *buf, int buflen):
    return ListItems(dir,buf,buflen)`
```

In my script where I am using this function, I define a string buffer and a pointer to it of type `c_char_p`, and pass it to the function in place of 
the `buf` argument:

```
buf = c_types.create_string_buffer(100)
pBuf = c_char_p(addressof(buf))
PyListItems('someFolder',pBuf,100)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, c_char_p found

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, and strings (str-type) in Python 3 are Unicode objects. create_string_buffer creates C char arrays, so you are required to pass a bytes object. If you have a str object encode with an appropriate encoding to create a bytes object. Note there is a create_unicode_buffer that creates C wchar arrays as well and takes Python 3 str objects.

Comment: In fact, you should tag this or otherwise specify what version of C/Python.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6

Answer (score 2):

```
pBuf = c_char_p(addressof(buf))
```

You don't need this. `create_string_buffer` already returns a character array. Just do:

```
buf = c_types.create_string_buffer(100)
PyListItems('someFolder',buf,100)
```

Comment: I am still getting an error:  > TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, c_char_Array_100 found